# Building for iOS, but linking in object file built for Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I use this [capacitor-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/capacitor-background-fetch) plugin with my app. But it gives the below error when I built the app on the iOS platform. i.e. no issues with Android.

**Error:**

> ld: in
> /Users/sampath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eyizjewzpltdzgbapgcghtizmnbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TSBackgroundFetch.framework/TSBackgroundFetch(TSBackgroundFetch_vers.o),
> building for iOS, but linking in object file built for Mac Catalyst,
> file
> '/Users/sampath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eyizjewzpltdzgbapgcghtizmnbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TSBackgroundFetch.framework/TSBackgroundFetch'
> for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

package.json

```
{
"name": "se",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "se",
"homepage": "se",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"lint": "ng lint"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/common": "14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "14.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.0.0",
"@angular/router": "14.0.0",
"@angular/youtube-player": "^14.0.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "6.2.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "6.2.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/insomnia": "6.2.0",
"@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^3.0.1",
"@capacitor-community/bluetooth-le": "2.0.1",
"@capacitor/android": "4.3.0",
"@capacitor/app": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/browser": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/camera": "^4.1.4",
"@capacitor/core": "^4.3.0",
"@capacitor/device": "4.1.0",
"@capacitor/geolocation": "4.1.0",
"@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/ios": "4.4.0",
"@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/preferences": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/splash-screen": "4.1.0",
"@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
"@ionic/angular": "6.1.9",
"@transistorsoft/capacitor-background-fetch": "^1.0.3",
"@types/lodash": "4.14.185",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-insomnia": "4.3.0",
"dayjs": "1.11.5",
"ionicons": "6.0.3",
"lodash": "4.17.21",
"rxjs": "6.6.0",
"tslib": "2.2.0",
"zone.js": "0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2.10",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "13.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "14.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "14.0.0",
"@capacitor/cli": "^4.3.0",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "6.0.0",
"@types/node": "12.11.1",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
"eslint": "7.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
"ts-node": "8.3.0",
"typescript": "4.7.3"
},
"description": "se"
}
```

ionic info:

Ionic:

```
Ionic CLI : 6.19.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 6.1.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics : 14.0.0
@angular/cli : 14.0.0
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 6.0.0
```

Capacitor:

```
Capacitor CLI : 4.7.1
@capacitor/android : 4.3.0
@capacitor/core : 4.7.1
@capacitor/ios : 4.4.0
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
native-run : 1.7.2
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v16.14.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 8.5.0
OS : macOS
```

I use the latest:

```
XCode: 14.2
Mac OS: 13.2.1
```

**Important note:**

I do not have any issues with 100s of native plugins that I have used with my Ionic/Angular apps in the past. So only with this plugin. Please let me know the solution to this.

Sample app: https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/capacitor-background-fetch

Answer (score 0):

Close XCode and add this to your `Podfile` (usually `ios/App/Podfile`):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Now run `npx cap sync ios` and try it again.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this too? i.e.for reading more about this.

Comment: No, I copied this from an old project where I had a similar problem back then. Did it help?

Comment: I'll try this and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried that. But no difference. i.e. same error. Any other clue please?